# iOS retina image size limit?

Tags: html, ios, css, retina-display

I'm having an issue displaying my retina sprite sheet on iOS devices. It was displaying correctly original but now - since adding more images to the sprite - it no longer shows up on the front end.

I'm wondering if there is some sort of size limit to images that can be displayed on iOS? The sprite itself is very large in terms of pixels (thankfully not in terms of file size). 1780 x 6300.

I've search around and this blog says there is a size limit: 
http://dev.billysbilling.com/blog/The-retina-trifecta-CSS-sprites-IMG-tags-and-SVGs-oh-my

Is it true?

Comment: Filesize on disk is not image size in memory, your image 1780x6300 is around 32MiB in memory (assuming 8-bit rgb). Apple advise for native apps is to split into tiles images larger than 1024x1024, I suppose it applies to webpages as well (maybe there is some optimisation done by browser, but anyway, anytime you're using your sprite you'r loading such big thing into device memory)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On very old iOS devices, the largest texture that can be created in OpenGL is 1024x1024. Newer devices support 2048x2048 and higher. It's unlikely that any devices support textures larger than 4096x4096. Try those 3 sizes and see which is the largest that work for the devices you're targeting. Non-square textures are limited to the same maximum width or height as a square texture.

Comment: Thanks Idles, I've removed some of the images from my sprite sheet and it is now pulling them through. I'll run a quick test shortly to see what the highest dimension I can get to pull through is and report back.

Comment: After to some experimenting it seems that my iPad 2 can't handle any images that are larger than 5 megapixels. Strange that I wasn't able to find anymore information of others that have run into this problem.

Comment: It's pretty common. All of the iOS user interface elements are built upon OpenGL, so the OpenGL texture size limits will apply to web content, in this case.

Comment: Ah ok understood. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.